# Insert break line after specific character in file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to insert a break line after a specific character in C# reading from a text file. I have a text file like

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"T:\data.txt");
```

and it contains a very big one line text (below is just a small portion of that).

```
"dep-1" : "M579.01303,612.20699L578.77297,612.20699 L578.77297,611.967L579.01303 Z","dep-2" : "M579.01303,612.20699L578.77297,612.20699 L578.77297,611.967L579.01303 Z","dep-3" : "M579.01303,612.20699L578.77297,612.20699 L578.77297,611.967L579.01303 Z"
```

Now I need to enter break line after **Z ",** and save the file. Then the text will formatted as:

```
"dep-1" : "M579.01303,612.20699L578.77297,612.20699 L578.77297,611.967L579.01303 Z",
"dep-2" : "M579.01303,612.20699L578.77297,612.20699 L578.77297,611.967L579.01303 Z",
"dep-3" : "M579.01303,612.20699L578.77297,612.20699 L578.77297,611.967L579.01303 Z"
```

Is this possible in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"T:\data.txt");
string newText = string.Join("Z\", \r\n", 
            text.Split(new[] { "Z\"," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

File.WriteAllText("path", newText);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
     lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("Z\",", "Z\"," + Environment.NewLine);
File.WriteAllLines(lines, path);
```

basic idea is you read all the lines, then you just replace the Z" with Z" plus a newline. After that you write all the lines to the same location.

Ok here is my edit for when all the text is the same line, (god damn trick questions);

```
 string file = File.ReadAllText(path);
 file.Replace("Z\",", "Z\"," + Environment.NewLine);
 File.WriteAllText(path);
```

Comment: The text is a little unclear but the example breaks after the ','

Comment: @HenkHolterman +1 for giving the solution the user wants not the one they ask for.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ty for you have given me the milestone upvote which made my rep exceed 10k, my whole life has been for this moment lolz

Comment: @Prix well I am only 15 :p

Comment: @evanmcdonnal then I'm bigger don't end it too soon :)

Comment: this doesn't work if all text in the same line! which is the actual case

Comment: @Prix right I missed that. my stupidity. I mixed this with my answer, which I didn't use replace :) but still it's wrong. he is trying to change loop variable (line) inside of foreach.that doesn't even compile

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I think you should remove the first solution or change it to for loop.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong (and that for a 10k user!). Replace the foreach with a regular `for (int i = 0; ...)` or just stick with ReadAlltext

Comment: @HenkHolterman yeah it occurred to me that the foreach isn't actually changing the items in the collection because line is a local var :(

Answer (score -2):

Simply write:

```
 text = text.Replace("Z", "Z\n");
```